# Problems with "zsh: command not found: sails"

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, ubuntu-14.04

I installed sails.js with via `sudo npm install -g sails` but i'm still getting `zsh: command not found: sails`

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: What is the output of `which npm`?

Answer (score 1):

First find out path for node `which node` will return something like `/path/bin/node`

enter that location to bin `cd /path`

uninstall present node by running
`rm -r bin/node bin/node-waf include/node lib/node lib/pkgconfig/nodejs.pc share/man/man1/node.1`

then you'll want to install nvm by running 
`curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.19.0/install.sh | bash` then `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` and `nvm install stable`

install node `npm -g i node`

finally install sails globally `npm -g i sails`

you should be good to build you first sails project