# Command not found using Sails.js

Tags: terminal, sails.js

My laptop is Mac and I downloaded the sail.js in the terminal but I failed to create a new sails app.

```
Last login: Thu Oct 15 15:17:37 on ttys000

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
Laude-MacBook-Air:~ laujoe$ npm install -g sails
/Users/laujoe/.npm-global/bin/sails -> /Users/laujoe/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/sails/bin/sails.js
+ sails@1.4.0
updated 1 package in 4.907s
Laude-MacBook-Air:~ laujoe$ sails new project
-bash: sails: command not found
Laude-MacBook-Air:~ laujoe$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with "zsh: command not found: sails"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815540/problems-with-zsh-command-not-found-sails)

Comment: thx, but still can't

Comment: Problem sovled. 
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/laujoe/.npm-global/bin"